# Can a Google Cloud Function communicate through a WebSocket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, websocket, cloud, serverless

Our many end users will, through a web browser, read and write in partly overlapping data.
When a user makes a change, a related change should be broadcasted to relevant other users.

Example use case: Several end users, each on their own device, look at a calendar with available time blocks to make an appointment. One of them creates an appointment, causing that a time block is not available for others anymore. The calendar on the screens of those others is updated accordingly and immediately.

Technically this would mean:

- Browser sends 'create appointment' event through WebSocket
- This event spins up a Cloud Function, which does the following (and then terminates):

  - Reserve the required capacity in the database
  - If this causes that the used time block is not available anymore for other users: Broadcast a 'not available anymore' event through the WebSockets of those other users that are viewing this time block.

In Google Cloud this is possible using an Apigee Java callout, where the Java (if needed) calls a Cloud Function, as described on https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/develop/how-create-java-callout. However, Apigee runs in Kubernetes (https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/hybrid/kubernetes-resources), causing the overhead of containers being up at moments when they are not or sparsely used.

Google Clouds API Gateway https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway doesn't support WebSockets: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176472002?pli=1

Is there a way to accomplish our goal through a Cloud Function, without any container?

Comment: Why do you need an API gateway?

Comment: We need a WebSocket to broadcast changes to relevant users. An API gateway is a possible way to implement a WebSocket.

Comment: Yes, but you can do without, and connect directly Cloud Run (better than cloud function, because you will have less endpoint. API Gateway are especially interesting when you have multiple endpoints, as you have with Lambda, but Cloud Run can aggregate them)